# Visual Studio 2015 iOS Build Failed to acquire Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have developed a mobile app with cordova and visual studio 2015.

When I try to build this app for iOS on a Windows host which is connected to a Mac with remotebuild agent, then I get this Error Message "Failed to acquire Cordova version 4.3.0":

```
>  ------ Submitting new build request to: http://10.25.100.62:3000/cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=4.3.0&cfg=debug&options=--device&loglevel=silly (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ New Build information: {"command":"build","vcordova":"4.3.0","cfg":"debug","options":"--device","loglevel":"silly","status":"Uploaded","buildCommand":"build","buildPlatform":"ios","configuration":"debug","buildLang":"en-US","buildDir":"/Users/administrator/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/19368","buildNumber":19368,"logLevel":0,"submissionTime":"2015-11-10T11:38:54.521Z","changeList":null,"buildSuccessful":false,"messageArgs":null,"message":"Uploaded build request payload.","tgzFilePath":"/Users/administrator/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/19368/upload_19368.tgz","appDir":"/Users/administrator/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/19368/cordovaApp","statusTime":"2015-11-10T11:38:55.514Z"} (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ 12:38:55 Checking on build status from http://10.25.100.62:3000/cordova/build/tasks/19368 [Attempt 1] (TaskId:11)
1>  uploaded - Uploaded build request payload. (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ 12:39:00 Checking on build status from http://10.25.100.62:3000/cordova/build/tasks/19368 [Attempt 2] (TaskId:11)
1>  building - Acquiring Cordova. (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ 12:39:05 Checking on build status from http://10.25.100.62:3000/cordova/build/tasks/19368 [Attempt 3] (TaskId:11)
1>  building - Acquiring Cordova. (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ 12:39:10 Checking on build status from http://10.25.100.62:3000/cordova/build/tasks/19368 [Attempt 4] (TaskId:11)
1>MDAVSCLI : error - error : Failed to acquire Cordova version 4.3.0. TACO0204: Error installing cordova via npm. Exit Code: 1. See output for details.
1>   (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ Remote build log follows (TaskId:11)
1>  npm WARN invalid config loglevel="undefined" (TaskId:11)
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"5.0.0","npm":"3.3.12"}) (TaskId:11)
1>  npm WARN install:rimraf@2.2.0 ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/administrator/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/bin.js' (TaskId:11)
1>  /Users/administrator/.taco_home/node_modules/cordova/4.3.0 (TaskId:11)
```

I already did all the steps descripted in the [official documentation](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? You may need to set the proxy server on the remote Mac.

Comment: To clarify - I meant setting the proxy server on the Mac so npm can download Cordova.

Comment: @MichaelBraude can you tell me how to configure it ?